# Pull interlinked records based on rank and latest timestamp

Tags: oracle

I have a table like below.

**myTable**:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id  |   ref         |   type    |   status  |   update_dt
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id1 |   m1123       |   10      |   1       | 03-NOV-22 10.44.64.104000000 AM
id1 |   m2123       |   10      |   2       | 03-NOV-22 10.44.64.104000000 AM
id1 |   s1123       |   20      |           | 03-NOV-22 10.44.64.104000000 AM
id1 |   s2123       |   20      |           | 03-NOV-22 10.44.54.104000000 AM
id1 |   p1123       |   30      |           | 03-NOV-22 10.44.54.104000000 AM

id2 |   m1234       |   10      |           | 02-NOV-22 10.44.64.104000000 AM
id2 |   s1234       |   20      |           | 02-NOV-22 10.44.54.104000000 AM
id2 |   s2234       |   20      |           | 02-NOV-22 10.44.54.104000000 AM

id3 |   m1345       |   10      |   1       | 01-NOV-22 10.44.64.104000000 AM
id3 |   s1345       |   20      |           | 01-NOV-22 10.44.64.104000000 AM
id3 |   s2345       |   20      |           | 01-NOV-22 10.44.54.104000000 AM
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My requirement looks pretty complex to me and I have tried to reach somewhere but not completely there. Here are my requirements.

1. From the table, I have to pull records of type 10 and 20 alone. With type 10 having status either null or 1.
2. For type 10 comparison, I need to convert the update_dt to epoch and pull all the type 10 records above a specific epoch.
3. type 10 records are linked to type 20 records by the id. They have the same id.
4. For all the records pulled in step 2, need to pull their corresponding type 20 records. But only the latest one based on update_dt.
5. If multiple records of type 20 has the same update_dt from step 4, any one of them can be picked.

By the above requirements, I need to get a result like for a sample epoch that corresponds to `Nov 1 2022 - 11AM (1667300400)`:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ref1    |   ref2    |   ref1_update_dt                  |   ref2_update_dt
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
m1123   |   s1123   |   03-NOV-22 10.44.64.104000000 AM |   03-NOV-22 10.44.64.104000000 AM
m1234   |   s2234   |   02-NOV-22 10.44.64.104000000 AM |   02-NOV-22 10.44.54.104000000 AM
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I tried the below. But didnt quite get there.

```
WITH cte_latest AS
(
SELECT
    t1.ref ref1,
    t2.ref ref2,
    t1.update_dt ref1_update_dt,
    t2.update_dt ref2_update_dt,
    RANK() OVER(ORDER BY t2.update_dt DESC) rank_temp
FROM
    myTable t1
JOIN myTable t2 ON
    t1.id = t2.id
WHERE
    t1.type = 10
    AND (t1.status IS NULL
        OR t1.status = 1)
    AND t2.type = 20
    AND (CAST(t1.update_dt AS DATE) - TO_DATE('01/01/1970', 'DD/MM/YYYY')) * 24 * 60 * 60 > '1667300400')
SELECT
    ref1,
    ref2,
    ref1_update_dt,
    ref2_update_dt
FROM
    cte_latest
WHERE
    rank_temp = 1
ORDER BY
    ref1_update_dt;
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

[RANK](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/RANK.html#GUID-0950BD34-C994-41DA-A8F9-34B3FE53BBBA) will return the same number when there are multiple type 20 records that have the same update_dt. So, you will want to use [ROW_NUMBER](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/ROW_NUMBER.html#GUID-D5A157F8-0F53-45BD-BF8C-AE79B1DB8C41) instead. That will ensure that each type 20 row gets a unique number to break any ties - per rule #5.

Also, you will need to partition the **ROW_NUMBER** based on the id of the type 10 records. That will cause the numbering to reset at 1 for each type 10 record id. Without partitioning every row in the result set would get a unique number.

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.id ORDER BY t2.update_dt DESC)
```